# I want to know what not integer numbers means in calendar?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, decimal-expansion, calendar-computations

I want to know what not integer numbers means in this case?
if $30$ days $= 4$ weeks and $2$ days $4.2$

then why $20$ days does not correspond to $2$ weeks and $8$days $4,8$?

being that: $\frac{30}{7} =$ $4.28571428571$ and $\frac{20}{7} = 2.85714285714$

Comment: $1$ day is not $1/10$ of a week but $1/7$ of a week, so $4$ weeks and $2$ days is not $4.2$ weeks, but $4+2/7$ weeks, i.e., $30/7\approx 4.2857$ weeks.

Comment: 2 weeks is 14 days, so 20 days is 2 weeks and 6 days.

Comment: I was wrong because I was thinking that the first number after the comma / period was the number of days. When in fact I was looking in the wrong place of the division, The correct is that I should look to  the number of days corresponds to the rest of the division obtained from the result of the 30 days - 28 days (from 4 * 7).  So 20 - 14 (from 7*2) = 6 thank you.  And the 0,28.... or 0.85... is weeks not days, and because of this, is wrong  get the first algarism of 0,2... or 0,8... and confuse them with days.